# running git remote update all of a sudden returns fatal: unable to fork

Tags: git, bitbucket

I ran `git remote update` on a machine that has been connected and communicating with a repository for a long time. Today when i ran that command it returned the following:

```
Fetching origin
fatal: unable to fork
error: Could not fetch origin
```

I have similar issue now with `git pull origin master` returns `fatal: unable to fork`

It is a bitbucket repository. I didn't do any forks. What could have caused this?

**UPDATES**

- Tried rebooting...same issue after restart
- Checked file permissions were normal
- Checked system resources (plenty of RAM and disk space left)
- Can clone project into a new directory on the same machine but still trying to figure out what made the project in its original directory broken.

What i ended up doing to get back to work was clone the repo again to a new folder and replacing the `.git` directory from the original directory with the one from the new clone.

I'm not sure what went wrong that caused this.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you're using ssh to fetch the remote and you don't have ssh installed. I've run into this with older versions of the alpine git docker image. See https://github.com/alpine-docker/git/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

The `fork` here isn't referring to a git fork; it means that the OS isn't able to allow the program to create a new thread. It's possible that your machine is running out of memory or there might be some other reason why it's not working; it might be worth trying a reboot to see if that fixes the problem.